# Serialize an NSMutableArray with Objects inside

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, serialization, ios4

I have an NSMutableArray with a bunch of Points(it's a class defined by me) inside. And I want to serialize this NSMutableArray to save to my disk. If I implement in my class Point the NSCoding protocol is it possible to use NSKeyedArchiver directly in my NSMutableArray?

Just like this example:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData new];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:myArray forKey:@"array"];
[data writeToFile:filename attomically:YES];
[archiver release];
[data release];
```

Comment: should be fine as long as you implement NSCoding, NSCopying for Point correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, quoting [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) :

> The NSArray class adopts the NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, and **NSCoding** protocols;

Note that if you're working with **points**, maybe you should use the Apple `CGPoint` structure, which comes with many handy utilities : `CGPointFromString` and `NSStringFromCGPoint` [see Apple documentation for more information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

And also these others ones might interest you `CGPointEqualToPoint`, `CGRectContainsPoint`, `CGRectIntersectsRect` or `CGRectContainsRect`... [see Apple documentation for more information](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: The problem is that i store more information than just position :( but thanx anyway for the answer

Comment: Then you could have your Point class having a coordinate property of type CGPoint. And your class could even expose x / y of the inner structure... That way you would get both aspects. Or why not just use CGPoint as temp vars when encoding/decoding...